# Pandas df plot x-axis date labels reformatting

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

would appreciate any help as I haven't found any questions covering this.

I'm plotting a line graph with date on x axis:

```
df = pd.read_csv('random.csv')
df.plot('date', 'y')
plt.xlabel('Dates')
plt.ylabel('Y')
```

It looks exactly how I want it to except the dates on the x-axis are in YYYY-MM-DD format which is difficult to read so would rather it was just YYYY-MM for legibility. Is there any easy way to do this that I'm missing?

I don't want to change the actual line plot in any way just the labels on the x-axis if that makes sense.

Any help is massively appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the `date` column is in `datetime` format, either on reading of the csv file:

`pd.read_csv('random.csv', parse_dates=['date'])`

or after:

`df['date']= pd.to_datetime(df['date'])`

Pandas generally does a good job adjusting the x-axis labels automatically for readability:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2015-02-24', periods=5, freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': rng, 'Val': np.random.randn(len(rng))})
df.plot('Date', 'Val')
```

[image]